# Problem with compilation (color)

Tags: errors, color

I have this code in LaTeX (the .cls file is [HERE](http://exdb.fit.cvut.cz/browser/zp/1213-zima/martiada/FITthesis.cls?rev=1217)):

```
\documentclass[thesis=B,czech]{FITthesis}[2012/06/26]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{dirtree}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

...and I have an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                              }\aftergroup \reset@color 
l.65 \begin{document}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: How do  I download the `.cls` file from there?

Comment: At the bottom of that page is "Download in other formats:".

Comment: I have added \RequirePackage{xcolor} in your FITthesis.cls file. Color related error OK but after this, give error on \titlepage and \department declaration. I think you can solve these errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On lines 395-399 of `FITthesis.cls` one finds:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
    \if@langczech\frontmatter*\else\frontmatter\fi %cislovani stranek pred prvni kapitolou
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \if@langczech{Sem vlo{\v z}te zad{\' a}n{\' i} Va{\v s}{\' i} pr{\' a}ce.}\else{Insert here your thesis' task.}\fi
```

and this reveals the culprit: code used in `\AtBeginDocument` is still part of the preamble and the class is using the hook to typeset information (in the fourth line in the code I showed above); this, of course, produces an error. The only remedy I see (perhaps there are better options), is to edit the `.cls` file and to replace the line

```
\AtBeginDocument{
```

with the two lines

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndPreamble{
```

so the new lines will look like

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndPreamble{
    \if@langczech\frontmatter*\else\frontmatter\fi %cislovani stranek pred prvni kapitolou
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \if@langczech{Sem vlo{\v z}te zad{\' a}n{\' i} Va{\v s}{\' i} pr{\' a}ce.}\else{Insert here your thesis' task.}\fi
```

the description of `\AfterEndPreamble` from `etoolbox`:

> `\AfterEndPreamble{<code>}` This hook differs from `\AtBeginDocument` in
>   that the code is executed at the very end of `\begin{document}`, after
>   any `\AtBeginDocument` code.

You should contact the author/maintainer of the class and report this bug.